# Assigning class position for each student in a class based on the sum of the total score across all results

Tags: php, get, position, prepared-statement, rank

Please I am trying to assign class positions eg) ist, 2nd , 3rd etc in each class according to who has highest score when the aggregate scores is summed
will appreciate any help
[The image added is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXhLo.png)

```
<div> 
 <?php
$classid;
$studentid;
$term;

$query8= $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(Aggregate) AS Aggregate , StudentId FROM tblresult WHERE ClassId=? and Term=? GROUP BY StudentId ORDER BY SUM(Aggregate) DESC");
 $query8->execute(array($classid,$term));

//$results8 = $query8-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $results8 = $query8-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$i=0;
$u=0;
echo $studentid."<br>";
foreach($results8 as $result8){
    $i++;
     
    echo $Sid = $i.'-'.$result8['Aggregate'].'-----'.$Students_id=$result8['StudentId']."<br>";  
 //$position = array_search($studentid, $Students_id);
   
}

//$position = array_search($studentid, $Students_id);
//Position: echo $position;
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how i do it, but you have to put the class_id & student_id as list to give you a meaning result.

```
   try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pwd');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    
    
    // $classid;
    // $studentid;
    $classid='18';
    $studentid='19';
    $term = 'First term';
    
    
    $query8 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT StudentId, SUM(Aggregate) FROM tblresult  WHERE ClassId=? and Term=? ORDER BY SUM(Aggregate) DESC");
    $query8->execute(array($classid,$term));
    
    $results8 = $query8-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $position = 1;
    
    foreach($results8 as $result8){
        $studentName = $result8['StudentId'];
        $aggregateScore = $result8['SUM(Aggregate)'];
        echo $position . ": " . $studentName . " - " . $aggregateScore . "<br>";
        $position++;
    }
```

I simulate you db Table, and here is the structure:
[image]

Comment: thanks for you contribuion. I tried this but didnt work for me. However I have an array of the scores sorted from highest to lowest. How do I get the index of each array element using php pdo? I think yhis will solve it ...... eg) array_search($studentid,array_keys($Students_id));

Comment: Can you share the data table with screen of the expected result.